# Is there a way to provide data deletion in Settings -> Usage like the Podcasts app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In iOS, if you go to Settings -> Usage -> Podcasts, it will let you individually delete podcasts to free up space. Is there an API to implement this in you own application? I want my app to expose some of its data for deletion.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Really interesting question, but I think since the podcast app is made by Apple they are using some private API.

Comment: I think so too after searching on Google but i wanted to ask the hive mind before i drop this :)